# HTTP Basic Auth with ActiveDirectory user/pass lookup

Tags: java, apache, authentication, active-directory, ldap

This link works well for a single user/password HTTP basic auth
http://lambda.fortytools.com/post/26977061125/servlet-filter-for-http-basic-auth

Does anyone have any snippets for HTTP basic auth that authenticates against ActiveDirectory user/password?

Comment: which technologies would you like to use?
eg. in spring it can be done almost out of the box

Comment: a simple jar, not concerned with the framework used to generate the jar

Comment: http://fm4dd.com/security/apache-ldap-active-directory.htm and https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Authenticating_Apache_against_Active_Directory and many others.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at this example [here](https://mhimu.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/active-directory-authentication-using-javajndi/) and change the source e.g. from [here](https://gist.github.com/neolitec/8953607) to use the code from the first link.

Link#1 content:

```
public class ADAuthenticator 
{
  private String domain;
  private String ldapHost;
  private String searchBase;

  public ADAuthenticator()
  {
    this.domain = "<your domain>";
    this.ldapHost = "ldap://<your AD controller>";
    this.searchBase = "your AD root e.g. dc=abbl,dc=org";
  }

  public ADAuthenticator(String domain, String host, String dn)
  {
    this.domain = domain;
    this.ldapHost = host;
    this.searchBase = dn;
  }

  public Map authenticate(String user, String pass)
  {
    String returnedAtts[] ={ "sn", "givenName", "mail" };
    String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + user + "))";

    //Create the search controls
    SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
    searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);

    //Specify the search scope
    searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapHost);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user + "@" + domain);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pass);

    LdapContext ctxGC = null;

    try
    {
      ctxGC = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
      //Search objects in GC using filters
      NamingEnumeration answer = ctxGC.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
      while (answer.hasMoreElements())
      {
        SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();
        Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
        Map amap = null;
        if (attrs != null)
        {
          amap = new HashMap();
          NamingEnumeration ne = attrs.getAll();
          while (ne.hasMore())
          {
            Attribute attr = (Attribute) ne.next();
            amap.put(attr.getID(), attr.get());
          }
          ne.close();
        }
          return amap;
      }
    }
    catch (NamingException ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Link#2 content:

```
public class BasicAuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

  /** Logger */
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

  private String username = "";

  private String password = "";

  private String realm = "Protected";

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    username = filterConfig.getInitParameter("username");
    password = filterConfig.getInitParameter("password");
    String paramRealm = filterConfig.getInitParameter("realm");
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(paramRealm)) {
      realm = paramRealm;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (authHeader != null) {
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(authHeader);
      if (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String basic = st.nextToken();

        if (basic.equalsIgnoreCase("Basic")) {
          try {
            String credentials = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(st.nextToken()), "UTF-8");
            LOG.debug("Credentials: " + credentials);
            int p = credentials.indexOf(":");
            if (p != -1) {
              String _username = credentials.substring(0, p).trim();
              String _password = credentials.substring(p + 1).trim();

              if (!username.equals(_username) || !password.equals(_password)) {
                unauthorized(response, "Bad credentials");
              }

              filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            } else {
              unauthorized(response, "Invalid authentication token");
            }
          } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new Error("Couldn't retrieve authentication", e);
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      unauthorized(response);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
  }

  private void unauthorized(HttpServletResponse response, String message) throws IOException {
    response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"" + realm + "\"");
    response.sendError(401, message);
  }

  private void unauthorized(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    unauthorized(response, "Unauthorized");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

At this [link](https://www.ziaconsulting.com/developer-help/spring-security-active-directory/) you can find a good example using Spring Security.

Basically you should create a class to extend **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** and overriding the *configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)* method.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

@Value("${ldap.url:ldap://mycompany.com:389}") private String url;
@Value("${ldap.domain}:mycompany.com") private String domain;
@Value("${ldap.userDNPattern:}") private String userDNPattern;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .httpBasic();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider = 
                new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(domain,url);
    adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

    // set pattern if it exists
    // The following example would authenticate a user if they were a member
    // of the ServiceAccounts group
    // (&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0})
    //   (memberof=CN=ServiceAccounts,OU=alfresco,DC=mycompany,DC=com))
    if (userDNPattern != null && userDNPattern.trim().length() > 0)
    {
        adProvider.setSearchFilter(userDNPattern);
    }
    auth.authenticationProvider(adProvider);

    // don't erase credentials if you plan to get them later
    // (e.g using them for another web service call)
    auth.eraseCredentials(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think "a simple jar, not concerned with the framework used to generate the jar" excludes spring too... but I'm not sure